# Como trocar mensagens com cliente e servidor java Socket?

Tags: java, sistemas-distribuídos

Não estou conseguindo fazer a troca de mensagens de servidor para o cliente java Socket.

O servidor está pronto, mas o cliente não consegue fazer de acordo com o servidor. Qual é a classe que envia mensagem para o servidor?

Segue abaixo as questões a se responder:

1)  Envia mensagem para o Servidor. A mensagem deve conter o nome do cliente.

2)  Recebe mensagem do Cliente.

3)  Envia mensagem ao Cliente, solicitando ao cliente que envie um código de verificação gerado aleatoriamente.

4)  Recebe mensagem do Servidor.

5)  Envia mensagem ao Servidor contendo o código de segurança enviado por ele na mensagem anterior.

Classe Servidor:

```
package SD_Server;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class MessageServer {

    public static int DEFAULT_PORT = 9999; 

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int serverPort = args.length > 0 ? Integer.parseInt(args[0])
                : DEFAULT_PORT;
        try {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(serverPort);
            while (true) {
                System.out.println("Aguardando conexao no endereco: "
                        + InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress() + ":"
                        + serverPort);
                Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                Connection connection = new Connection(clientSocket);
                System.out.println("Conexao feita com: "
                        + clientSocket.getInetAddress() + ":"
                        + clientSocket.getPort());
            } 
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class Connection extends Thread {
    private DataInputStream in;
    private DataOutputStream out; 
    private Socket clientSocket;

    public Connection(Socket aClientSocket) {
        try {
            clientSocket = aClientSocket;
            in = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            out = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            this.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String currentTime() {
        return "[" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "]";
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            // 1: Recebe mensagem com nome se nome
            String msg = in.readUTF();
            System.out.println(currentTime() + " Mensagem recebida de " 
                    + clientSocket.getInetAddress() + ": " + msg);

            // 2: Envia mensagem com codigo de verificacao
            int random4digits = 1000 + (int) (Math.random() * 9999);
            out.writeUTF("Retorne mensagem com o codigo de verificacao: "
                    + random4digits);
            System.out.println(currentTime() + " Enviado para "
                    + clientSocket.getInetAddress() + " o codigo: "
                    + random4digits);

            // 3: Recebe mensagem com codigo de verificacao
            msg = in.readUTF();
            System.out.println(currentTime() + " Mensagem recebida de "
                    + clientSocket.getInetAddress() + ": " + msg);
        } catch (EOFException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                clientSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Segue a classe Cliente:

```
package SD_Server;

import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MessageCliente {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, Exception {
        // Estabelecendo conexao na porta 9999 do servidor! 
        //System.out.println("Estabelecendo conexao com o servidor..");
        Socket clientSocket = new Socket();  




        // recupera as mensagens recebidas do servidor
        Scanner saida = new Scanner(clientSocket.getInputStream());  
        // Envia mensagem para o servidor e o servidor traz a mensagem para o cliente
        // Ler a mensagem do servidor 
        System.out.println("Cliente recebe a mensagem do servidor:  "+saida.next());  
        saida.close(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Classe Cliente:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Cliente {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Socket socket = null;
        
        InputStreamReader leitorDados = null; 
        OutputStreamWriter escritorDados = null;
        
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;  
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter =null; 
        
        try {
            socket = new Socket("localhost", 1234);
            
            leitorDados = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
            escritorDados = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
            
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(leitorDados);
            bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(escritorDados);
            
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
            
            while(true) {
                String mensagem = scanner.nextLine();
                bufferedWriter.write(mensagem);
                bufferedWriter.newLine(); 
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                
                System.out.println("SERVIDOR: " + bufferedReader.readLine());
                
                if(mensagem.equalsIgnoreCase("tchau")) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            
            try {
            socket.close();
            leitorDados.close();
            escritorDados.close();
            bufferedReader.close();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Classe servidor:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Servidor {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Socket socket = null;
        
        InputStreamReader leitorDados = null;
        OutputStreamWriter escritorDados = null;
        
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = null;
        
        ServerSocket socketServidor = null;
        socketServidor = new ServerSocket(1234);
        
        while(true) {
            try {
                socket = socketServidor.accept();
                
                leitorDados = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
                escritorDados = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
                
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(leitorDados);
                bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(escritorDados);
                
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
                
                while(true) {
                    String mensagemClienteRecebe = scanner.nextLine();
                    String mensagemCliente = bufferedReader.readLine();
                    
                    System.out.println("Cleinte mandou: " + mensagemCliente);
                    
                    bufferedWriter.write("Mensagem recebida: " + mensagemClienteRecebe);
                    bufferedWriter.newLine();
                    bufferedWriter.flush();
                    
                    if(mensagemCliente.equalsIgnoreCase("tchau")) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                socket.close();
                leitorDados.close();
                escritorDados.close();
                bufferedReader.close();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```